# Ng --prod causes refresh on deploy after clicking the button

Tags: angular, deployment, production-environment

My project works perfectly when I run the project via 'Ng Serve or Ng serves --aot', however in production mode (--prod) it happens refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely due to incompatibility between some npm packages. If you use Angular CLI, you should do the following (This is the easiest way I can help based on your provided info):

- upgrade Angular CLI by running this command in the terminal `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.2`.
- Next, in your `package.json` file, ensure that your npm packages have the same versions & semantic versioning i.e. `*`, `^` or `~` as the ones as follows (I got this by generating a project using Angular CLI 1.6.2):

  Remember to keep any libraries other than the following that you still use!

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

- Then, in your project folder where `package.json` is located,  remove the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.
- After the installation has finished, you can try having your project built for production and see if it works.

Comment: Still giving the same problem :/

Comment: Then you can try removing the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again.

Comment: glad it worked :) please upvote my editted answer since it's useful for you. Thanks

Comment: Hello again! hahaha Would you tell me the procedure to do when this error occurs with Ionic?

Comment: Sorry. I don't have experience with Ionic. :|