# @types/async (DefinitelyTyped) errors when performing ng build

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, types, definitelytyped

So we have a site we created last year using:

- node v6.9.1
- npm v3.10.8
- angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.24
- typescript v2.1.4

This app was able to build last time the previous developer checked in.  Since getting a new developer, setting up the versions above and performing an ng build we are now getting new errors:

> ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,74): ']' expected.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,75): ';' expected.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,76): Declaration or statement expected.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,104): Expression expected.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (29,120): ')' expected.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (29,155): '(' expected.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,62): A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,63): Cannot find name 'K'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,68): Cannot find name 'keyof'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,74): Cannot find name 'R'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,78): Cannot find name 'AsyncAutoTask'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,92): Cannot find name 'R'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,94): Cannot find name 'K'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,98): Cannot find name 'R'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (28,101): Cannot find name 'E'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (29,114): Cannot find name 'keyof'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (29,120): Cannot find name 'R'.
>   ERROR in E:/code/score/node_modules/@types/async/index.d.ts (29,124): Cannot find name 'AsyncAutoTaskFunction'.`

Here are the dependencies and devDependencies sections of package.json:

  `"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.0",
    "angular2-apollo": "^0.9.0-rc.3",
    "apollo-client": "^0.7.1",
    "azure-storage": "^2.1.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "graphql-tag": "^1.2.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.32",
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/isomorphic-fetch": "0.0.31",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.60",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typed-graphql": "^1.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }`

The following is the output from npm outdated command:

    `$ npm outdated
    Package                                  Current         Wanted           Latest
    @angular/common                           2.4.10         2.4.10            5.2.0
    @angular/compiler                         2.4.10         2.4.10            5.2.0
    @angular/compiler-cli                     2.4.10         2.4.10            5.2.0
    @angular/core                             2.4.10         2.4.10            5.2.0
    @angular/forms                            2.4.10         2.4.10            5.2.0
    @angular/http                             2.4.10         2.4.10            5.2.0
    @angular/platform-browser                 2.4.10         2.4.10            5.2.0
    @angular/platform-browser-dynamic         2.4.10         2.4.10            5.2.0
    @angular/router                           3.4.10         3.4.10            5.2.0
    @types/chai                                3.5.2          3.5.2            4.1.0
    @types/file-saver                          0.0.0          0.0.0            1.3.0
    @types/isomorphic-fetch                   0.0.31         0.0.31           0.0.34
    @types/jasmine                            2.5.38         2.5.38            2.8.3
    @types/jquery                             2.0.48         2.0.48           3.2.17
    @types/node                               6.0.96         6.0.96            9.3.0
    angular-cli                        1.0.0-beta.24  1.0.0-beta.24  1.0.0-beta.28.3
    apollo-client                              0.7.3          0.7.3            2.2.0
    codelyzer                                  2.0.1          2.0.1            4.0.2
    graphql-tag                                1.3.2          1.3.2            2.6.1
    gulp-sourcemaps                            2.4.0          2.4.0            2.6.3
    jasmine-core                               2.5.2          2.5.2            2.8.0
    jasmine-spec-reporter                      2.5.0          2.5.0            4.2.1
    karma                                      1.2.0          1.2.0            2.0.0
    karma-remap-istanbul                       0.2.2          0.2.2            0.6.0
    protractor                                4.0.14         4.0.14            5.2.2
    ts-node                                    1.2.1          1.2.1            4.1.0
    tslint                                     4.5.1          4.5.1            5.9.1
    typescript                                2.0.10         2.0.10            2.6.2
    zone.js                                    0.7.8          0.7.8           0.8.20`

We are not sure how to resolve this issue as we have even tried updating node/npm/angular/typescript to other problems.

Any help/guidance/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not every version of every package is compatible with every version of other packages. You'll need to dig into the documentation for each one and figure out what its peer dependencies are and what it supports. Package management is a pain, and must be done very carefully and strategically for this reason. Can you post your dependencies and devDependencies listed in your `package.json` file and possibly the output of `npm outdated` on the machine it is failing on?

Comment: You can try my answer in this question to see if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054005/ng-prod-causes-refresh-on-deploy-after-clicking-the-button/48054600#48054600

Comment: Thanks @HT89, I had originally tried updating everything but that produced many more incompatibilities throughout the working code.  When we pulled down the code that was working and hadn't changed since the last successful deployment it would just give us the errors above.

Comment: Thanks @mhodges, I have edited the question to include the information you wanted to see.

Comment: @JeffL8 I see that typescript `2.0.10` is listed in your npm outdated output, however you said that you're using `2.1.4`. Can you clarify this discrepancy for me? Also, for future reference, putting `~` and `^` in your dependencies lists is a *really* bad idea for this very reason. You're not guaranteed the same version of the packages each time you `npm install` and therefore you can run into version conflicts

Comment: @JeffL8 It would also be helpful to compare the `npm outdated` output from a working system with the output you posted. That may show versioning differences.

Comment: @JeffL8 Try removing all `~` and `^` from your package.json dependencies/devDependencies, then delete your node_modules folder, then do an `npm install` and see if that works. Then if you want to upgrade packages, do them 1 at a time and hard-code the version into your package.json file, don't use `~` or `^`

Answer (score 0):

So after going through many versions of TypeScript (e.g. 2.0.10, 2.1.4 and the latest; 2.6.2) we stumbled upon a 2.1 (no revision, just major.minor: "typescript": "2.1") that resolved the build.  We found this odd but didn't fight it, made the change, checked it in and watched the CI/CD complete successfully.